# How to get Vista to auto Lock after x minutes

Tags: security, windows-vista

Usually in good shops, your network admin will somehow set everyone's OS to lock after a certain period of time to ensure security.  I liked this and I miss it.

My current network admin hasn't done this so tried to find a way to set that myself on my box.  Is there a way to do this in Vista?  I don't see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a password-protected screen saver.

1. Right-click on your desktop and choose Personalize
2. Click the Screen Saver option in the Personalize appearance and sounds window
3. Set a number of minutes and check the On resume, display logon screen checkbox.

Your screen will auto-lock after the number of minutes you set in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enable the password and check the password box for when it's woken up. Check [here](http://www.lockergnome.com/windows/2007/03/13/password-protected-screensaver-in-vista/)...